# Mismatch of values when using xml input in postgre sql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I want to create a xml format so that i can use it in the input of a stored procedure,but the result came from the select query is not the output i am expecting.Could you please help me with this?

```
WITH test_xml(data) AS (VALUES
('<ROOT>
<record Modelid="1" ModelName="Paul" description="abc" Productid="1"      Modelprice="120987">
    <record variationid="20" VariationName="1abc" Variationimage="1abc" variationdesc="1variationdesc">
      <item layerid="11" layeris="layer1.js"></item>
      <item layerid="12" layeris="layer2.js"></item>
    </record>
    <record variationid="21" VariationName="2abc" Variationimage="2abc" variationdesc="2variationdesc">
      <item layerid="13" layeris="layer3.js"></item>
      <item layerid="14" layeris="layer4.js"></item>
    </record>
</record>
</ROOT>'::XML)
)
SELECT  unnest((xpath('//record/@Modelid', test_xml.data))) as Modelid ,
unnest((xpath('//record/record/@variationid', test_xml.data))) as     variationid,
unnest((xpath('//record/record/item/@layerid', test_xml.data))) as layerid
FROM test_xml
```

Output is:

`modelid variationid layerid
1       20          11
1       21          12
1       20          13
1       21          14`

**but exactly what i want is**

`modelid variationid layerid
1       20          11
1       20          12
1       21          13
1       21          14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
WITH test_xml(data) AS (VALUES
('<ROOT>
<record Modelid="1" ModelName="Paul" description="abc" Productid="1" Modelprice="120987">
    <record variationid="20" VariationName="1abc" Variationimage="1abc" variationdesc="1variationdesc">
      <item layerid="11" layeris="layer1.js"></item>
      <item layerid="12" layeris="layer2.js"></item>
    </record>
    <record variationid="21" VariationName="2abc" Variationimage="2abc" variationdesc="2variationdesc">
      <item layerid="13" layeris="layer3.js"></item>
      <item layerid="14" layeris="layer4.js"></item>
    </record>
</record>
</ROOT>'::XML)
)
SELECT
   (xpath('//record/@Modelid', models.data))[1] AS modelid,
   (xpath('//record/@variationid', variations.data))[1] AS variationid,
   (xpath('//item/@layerid', layers.data))[1] AS layerid
FROM test_xml
   JOIN LATERAL unnest(xpath('//record', test_xml.data)) models(data) ON TRUE
   JOIN LATERAL unnest(xpath('//record/record', models.data)) variations(data) ON TRUE
   JOIN LATERAL unnest(xpath('//record/item', variations.data)) layers(data) ON TRUE;
```

Comment: Thanks it was working.....but i could not understand the function used LATERAL...

Comment: `LATERAL` is explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) - it means that later `FROM` list entries can refer to prior ones. So this query joins each model to all its valiations and each variation to all its layers. Then the respective data are extracted. The problem with your query was that there is no connection between the lists returned by the subselects.

Comment: Thanks,but is there any other ways to get the result?

Comment: Oh, I see, you are using an outdated PostgreSQL version too. Don't know if it can be done there too in some way. Perhaps with a query using `WITH`.